# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 fails from 17.10

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu version 17.01 to 18.04 but I get the following error:

> E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' no longer has a Release file.

would you please help me. 
I am attaching a picture of the error window.

[image]

by the way, I am sure that there is no problem in connection. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the Zesty URL from your `sources.list`. Use only the Artful sources. Zesty is [an EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) Ubuntu release its URLs isn't compatible with your current distribution.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then remove:

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security
```